# Java array list reference

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, reference, copy

I have two array list e.g.

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
integerList.add(new Integer(1));
integerList.add(new Integer(2));
integerList.add(new Integer(3));
integerList.add(new Integer(4));

ArrayList<Integer> tempTableau = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < integerList.size(); i++) {
    if (i >= 1 && i < 4) {
        tempTableau.add(integerList.get(i));
    }
}
```

what I would like to achieve is if I something like

```
tempTableau.set(1, new Integer(-2));
```

i.e. change the value in one array, it should also reflect the change in another array
or

```
System.out.println(integerList.get(2));
System.out.println(tempTableau.get(1));
```

should both output -2.

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> tempTableau = integerList;` would create another reference to the `List`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @GBlodgett I am working on a problem, which create a another array by copying the element from first array, but if we change the element in second array, it should also change the element in first array. Something to do with reference of an object in an array list. Is that something possible to do ?

Comment: @GendarmeThis is the problem that I am trying to solve. 
I am working on a problem, which create a another array by copying the element from first array, but if we change the element in second array, it should also change the element in first array. Something to do with reference of an object in an array list. Is that something possible to do ?

Comment: `Integer` (like `String`) is immutable. You can't change the value of an existing `Integer` object, you can only replace the reference to the `Integer` with a reference to another `Integer`. Try looking into `AtomicInteger`. You could put a reference to an AtomicInteger into two lists, and when you change the integer inside the `AtomicInteger` in one list, it will also be changed in the other list.

Comment: @user3678399 please see the update in my answer

Comment: @Kartik I just used Integer as an example. The actual problem has a generic list List<K> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
So I am not sure how to achieve the same using generic list.

Comment: @Jason I just used Integer as an example. The actual problem has a generic list List<K> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
So I am not sure how to achieve the same using generic list.

Comment: @user3678399 that's even better.. if `K` is a class, you can just use `K` instead of `AtomicInteger` in the code I showed

Comment: @Kartik How can I set the value of K.
 
integerList.get(0).set(60); // change value 50 to 60 in first list.

This will be compilation error.

Comment: @Kartik K can be anything, may be class or integer or AtomicInteger etc.

Comment: @user3678399 Added custom type to my answer, can't explain better than this.. I suggest you do some more reading on java

Answer (score 2):

If you want the two lists to be exactly the same, and changing one would change the other, you can make them refer to the same list like this:-

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> tempTableau = integerList;
```

If you want different lists, then it's not possible to do it with just a single `set()` call. You'll need to change the other list as well.

You may come up with your custom extension of `ArrayList`, which would take a listener and call that listener if anything changes.

**Update** based on comments:

You can create a wrapper class to wrap integer or use `AtomicInteger`:-

```
List<AtomicInteger> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
List<AtomicInteger> tempTableau = new ArrayList<>();

AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(50);
integerList.add(i);
tempTableau.add(i);

integerList.get(0).set(60); // change value 50 to 60 in first list
System.out.println(tempTableau.get(0).get()); // value changed in the second
```

**Update** based on further comments:

If it's a custom object like:-

```
public class MyCustomClass {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // many other fields

    // constructor, getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyCustomClass{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

You can create your own wrapper like this:-

```
class Holder<T> {

    private T object;

    Holder(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    T getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    void setObject(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your lists:-

```
    List<Holder<MyCustomClass>> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Holder<MyCustomClass>> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    MyCustomClass obj1 = new MyCustomClass("John", 18);

    Holder<MyCustomClass> holder1 = new Holder<>(obj1);
    listOne.add(holder1);
    listTwo.add(holder1);

    MyCustomClass obj2 = new MyCustomClass("Paul", 45);
    listOne.get(0).setObject(obj2); //make holder1 hold obj2 instead of obj1 in listOne

    System.out.println(listTwo.get(0).getObject()); //listTwo prints MyCustomClass{name='Paul', age=45}
```